# Get 1 value from MySQL table using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Im trying to retrieve the correct `user_id` for my user who is logging in to my website...

```
$result = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email_address= :em AND password= :pw");
$result->bindParam(':em', $user);
$result->bindParam(':pw', $password);
$result->execute();
$rows = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
if($rows > 0) {
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = 1;
    $_SESSION['uid'] = $rows['user_id'];
}
```

I want to get the relevant user_id and im trying to do so using `$rows['user_id'];` with no luck...

Comment: What does `fetch()` return? I think it's a result pointer rather than an array - you have to explicitly fetch the array. It also looks like you're returning ALL rows instead of just one, so `$rows['user_id']` would be undefined (`$rows[0]['user_id']` might work)

Comment: You might try `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` instead. "PDO::FETCH_NUM: returns an array indexed by column number as returned in your result set, starting at column 0" http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Answer (score 2):

You should use `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` instead of `PDO::FETCH_NUM`

And `fetch` return false when there is no result more, so you should do like:

```
$result->execute();
if ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = 1;
    $_SESSION['uid'] = $rows['user_id'];
}
```